# How to save a list of objects to a database that have a many to many relationship, using a stored procedure, in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, many-to-many

If I have a few C# object's in .NET Core, such as:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public List<House> Houses{ get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    public int HouseId { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
}

public class PersonHouse
{
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of `Person` which in turn contains a list of houses. Assuming I already have the database set up with the link table, how do I send the list to the database using the `SqlCommand` object?

I currently have no code to show as an example of what I have tried because I have absolutely no idea where to start on this one.

I am aware of how to save simple objects to a database via the `SqlCommand` object but have never actually came across a solution to save an object under these circumstances.

Before .NET Core I would use Entity Framework but that is not an option in this case.

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for [streaming](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+how+stream+objects+to+a+database%3F).

Comment: When you say "Entity Framework ... is not an option", have you looked at [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data)?